# Passing value from database through URL in PHP having spaces

Tags: php, mysql, url, get, concatenation

I am passing a variable value from database to one PHP page through URL and that variable value contains spaces in it. The values before the space is passing successfully but not after the space. What can i do to pass the complete value? The URL concatenation i've done is shown in below code. 
Please help!

```
<?php $linking = "appointment.php?name=";
$linking .="$row[5]";
echo "<a href=$linking>BOOK AN APPOINTMENT</a>" 
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Encode your values using `urlencode()`

Answer (score 2):

urlencode should do it. Also put double quotes around the href.

```
<?php $linking = "appointment.php?name=";
$linking .= urlencode($row[5]);
echo "<a href=\"$linking\">BOOK AN APPOINTMENT</a>" 
?>
```

A further improvement would be to add htmlspecialchars to protect against & characters in $row[5] and against " in it:

```
<?php $linking = "appointment.php?name=";
$linking .= urlencode($row[5]);
echo "<a href=\"".htmlspecialchars($linking, ENT_QUOTES)."\">BOOK AN APPOINTMENT</a>" 
?>
```

Comment: Yes @adder i appreciate your answer it gave me perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the space with a joker like "-" or anything you want, with str_replace for an example. Then when you retrieve it just replace the joker by space.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the [rawurlencode](https://www.php.net/rawurlencode).This will encode spaces as `%20` instead of +.

**urlencode** encodes spaces as + symbols while **rawurlencode** encodes as %20.

```
<?php 
$linking = "appointment.php?name=";
$linking .=rawurlencode($row[5]);
echo "<a href=$linking>BOOK AN APPOINTMENT</a>" 
?>
```